# import tensorflow failing in Jupyter notebook, but not Anaconda prompt

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I have created a tf2 tensorflow environment using Anaconda.  I can import tensorflow no issue via the command prompt.  When I activate this environment and launch Jupyter notebook, I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_20912/1332388178.py in <module>
      1 # TensorFlow and tf.keras
----> 2 import tensorflow as tf
      3 
      4 # Helper libraries
      5 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

I have created run this to add the kernel to Jupyter (although I thought it just launched using the current active conda environment anyway).

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name <Environment_Name>
```

But still no joy when explicitly using the tf2 kernel in Jupyter.  Although jupyter seems to be starting off the active tf2 environment anyway.

```
[I 13:58:30.178 NotebookApp] Kernel shutdown: 603e39de-2b2e-4228-86ce-b135811ea301
[I 13:58:30.438 NotebookApp] Kernel started: 98f24818-ae84-4947-9c88-9b1814d9c768, name: tf2
[I 13:59:49.915 NotebookApp] Saving file at /tensorflow/Fashion MNIST.ipynb
```

Comment: 'pip install tensorflow' in a cell in Jupyter

Comment: Why should I do that?  Don’t have to do it with any other package?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new environment for tensorflow using below code:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow python=3.5 
conda activate tf
```

As you have already created tf2 environment, activate the same environment in cmd prompt as below:

```
conda activate tf2
```

then insatll:

```
conda install pip
pip install tensorflow
```

Now, Select the `"tf2"`(you created) in anaconda environments and open the `JUPYTER notebook` in the same environment and type:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

if there is no error - tensorflow successfully installed.

You can check the tensorflow version -

```
print(tf.__version__)
```

Further, you can install any package using `!pip install package_name` in Jupyter Notebook.

Comment: Thanks, although was looking for a conda solution.  I have proxy issues using PIP and all kinds of SSL errors.

Comment: So, you can use `conda install tensorflow` in place of `pip install tensorlfow`.